# Add values to an existing custom entity bundle

Tags: entities

I've created a custom entity with bundle and added 3 fields to the bundle(namely recipient, sender, flag). How can I add values to it programmatically.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

One approach is using [entity_metadata_wrapper](https://drupal.org/node/1021556):

> The Entity API provides wrapper classes you may use to make dealing with the values of an entity's properties and fields easier.
>   Wrappers make it easier to get and set the values of fields and
>   properties as well as to programmatically retrieve additional
>   information about these elements and iterate over lists of values in a
>   consistent manner.

Example:

```
$entity_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('myentity', $id);
$var = $entity_wrapper->field_flag->value() + 1;
$entity_wrapper->field_flag->set($var);
$entity_wrapper->save();
```

Comment: Yes @jorgetutor, this was my thought, but i think in order to wrap your entity you have to have an existing entity(the second param in the entity_metadata_wrapper). My problem is i want to add a new value.

Comment: The second parameter also can be an ID. You can use the set() method to add a new value to your entity and then save it.

Answer (score 1):

So this is one way to do it. You have to build an object, then assign values to the fields you've created and call the entity_save:
("Blocking" entity type and an bundle with the same name).

```
$entity = new stdClass(); 
$entity->type = 'blocking';
$entity->field_recipient[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['uid'] = $user->uid;
$entity->field_sender[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['uid'] = $user_to_block;
$entity->field_blocked[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = 1;

entity_save('blocking',$entity);
```